# Array stored as String - How to extract pieces of it?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I got a problem with a specific database where some tags from a user profile are stored as a String data type, and so far I have not figured out how to fetch data from this one.

Example String:

```
{"watch_intro": "Gifts from my family.", "favorite_brands_styles": ["Fossil","Tudor","Omega"]}
```

I am looking to query into this field and get something like below:

```
'Fossil, Tudor, Omega'
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, found the answer:

```
array_to_string(PARSE_JSON(EXTRA_INFO):"favorite_brands_styles",', ') AS fav_brands
```